# How to configure the appearance of akka actor logging

Tags: scala, akka, logback

My classes are extending `LazyLogging` and I have a 
`logback-dev.xml` and a `logback-prod.xml` file.

I tried to play around with the `logback xml` files , for example:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%date{ISO8601} %-5level [%logger{0}] [%thread] %msg%n</pattern> << deleted this line , tried to modify it etc.
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="dev" level="DEBUG" />

<root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
</root>
```

but still my console logs look like this:

```
12:41:46.551 [DatafeedsTaskerSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-21] INFO com.dy.datafeeds.tasker.DatafeedsTasker - The actual message I care about
```

What I want is this format (more terse)

```
[time] [class_name/trait/etc. method_name] [file name] [line number of log] [level] The actual message I care about
```

so the previous message looks something like this

```
[12:41:57.833] [DatafeedsTasker Foo:] [DatafeedsTasker.scala] [Line 25] [INFO] The actual message I care about
```

And if it was a method from an inherited trait it should look like:

```
[12:41:57.833] [DatafeedsTasker Bar:] [TheTraitFile.scala] [Line 25] [INFO] The actual message I care about
```

Comment: are you sure its reading the right xm file ?

Comment: not sure at all, how do I check that

Comment: in akka config:
https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/configuration.html

using slf4j: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/logging.html#slf4j

in general take in mind that if u use slf4j directly i think it will block on each log statment until the lib will write it.

Comment: i need to configure in the xml